# How to retrieve the whole sentence around a selected word?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests, full-text-search

I would like to find a selected word and take everything from the first period(.) before it and up until the first period(.) after it.

example:

inside a file call 'text.php'

```
'The price of blueberries has gone way up. In the year 2038 blueberries have 
 almost tripled in price from what they were ten years ago. Economists have 
 said that berries may going up 300% what they are worth today.'
```

Code example: (I know that if i use a code like this i can find +5 before the word ['that'] and +5 after the word, but i would like to find everything between the period before and after a word.)

```
import re

text = 'The price of blueberries has gone way up, that might cause trouble for farmers.
In the year 2038 blueberries have almost tripled in price from what they were ten years 
ago. Economists have said that berries may going up 300% what they are worth today.'

find = 
re.search(r"(?:[a-zA-Z'-]+[^a-zA-Z'-]+){0,5}that(?:[^a-zA-Z'-]+[a-zA-Z'-]+){0,5}", text)
done = find.group()
print(done)
```

return:

```
'blueberries has gone way up, that might cause trouble for farmers'
```

I would like it to return every sentence with ['that'] in it.

Example return(what i'm looking to get):

```
'The price of blueberries has gone way up, that might cause trouble for farmers',
'Economists have said that berries may going up 300% what they are worth today'
```

Comment: What this `capital = (if get('test') then get('friendly'))` should do? This syntax is unacceptable in Python? Describe the logic of your script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
text = 'The price of blueberries has gone way up, that might cause trouble for farmers. In the year 2038 blueberries have almost tripled in price from what they were ten years ago. Economists have said that berries may going up 300% what they are worth today.'
for sentence in text.split('.'):
    if 'that' in sentence:
        print(sentence.strip())
```

`.strip()` is there simply to trim extra spaces because I'm splitting on `.`.

If you do want to use the `re` module, I would be using something like this:

```
text = 'The price of blueberries has gone way up, that might cause trouble for farmers. In the year 2038 blueberries have almost tripled in price from what they were ten years ago. Economists have said that berries may going up 300% what they are worth today.'
results = re.findall(r"[^.]+that[^.]+", text)
results = map(lambda x: x.strip(), results)
print(results)
```

To get the same results.

---

Things to keep in mind:

- If you have words like `thatcher` in the sentence, the sentence will be printed too. In the first solution, you could use `if 'that' in sentence.split():` instead so as to split the string into words, and in the second solution, you could use `re.findall(r"[^.]+\bthat\b[^.]+", text)` (note the `\b` tokens; these represent word boundaries).
- The script relies on period (`.`) to limit the sentences. If the sentence themselves contain words that use periods, then the results might not be the expected results (e.g. for the sentence `Dr. Tom is sick yet again today, so I'm substituting for him.`, the script will find `Dr` as one sentence and `Tom is sick yet again today, so I'm substituting for him.` as another sentence)

---

EDIT: To answer your question in the comments, I would make the following changes:

Solution 1:

```
text = 'The price of blueberries has gone way up, that might cause trouble for farmers. In the year 2038 blueberries have almost tripled in price from what they were ten years ago. Economists have said that berries may going up 300% what they are worth today.'
sentences = text.split('.')
for i, sentence in enumerate(sentences):
    if 'almost' in sentence:
        before = '' if i == 0 else sentences[i-1].strip()
        middle = sentence.strip()
        after = '' if i == len(sentences)-1 else sentences[i+1].strip()
        print(". ".join([before, middle, after]))
```

Solution 2:

```
text = 'The price of blueberries has gone way up, that might cause trouble for farmers. In the year 2038 blueberries have almost tripled in price from what they were ten years ago. Economists have said that berries may going up 300% what they are worth today.'
results = re.findall(r"(?:[^.]+\. )?[^.]+almost[^.]+(?:[^.]+\. )?", text)
results = map(lambda x: x.strip(), results)
print(results)
```

Note that these can potentially give overlapping results. E.g. if the text is `a. b. b. c.`, and you are trying to find sentences containing `b`, you will get `a. b. b` and `b. b. c`.

Comment: This works extremely well and exactly what i'm looking for, just for my own curiosity would there be a way to find the the sentence both and after that sentence that is found. i would think that this could be achieved by using the same code as you provided but skipping every other "."(period)

Comment: @johnsmith sorry, I'm not quite sure what you mean here :s

Comment: lets say i put the word 'almost' in the script instead of the word 'that' and want to get all three sentences so it returns: 'The price of blueberries has gone way up. In the year 2038 blueberries have almost tripled in price from what they were ten years ago. Economists have said that berries may going up 300% what they are worth today.' what would i add to the script to return not only the sentence that contains the word 'almost' but also the sentence before and after it. would that be possible?

Comment: @johnsmith ahh! Yes it's possible, not quite easy to put in the comments though um, I'll add it to my answer in a few

Comment: @johnsmith ok added

Comment: It works great, thank you that's going to save me a ton of time

Answer (score 0):

This function should do the job:

```
old_text = 'test 1: test friendly, test 2: not friendly, test 3: test friendly, test 4: not friendly, test 5: not friendly'

replace_dict={'test 1':'tested 1','not':'very'}
```

The function:

```
def replace_me(text,replace_dict):
     for key in replace_dict.keys():
          text=text.replace(str(key),str(replace_dict[key]))
     return text
```

result:

```
 print(replace_me(old_text,replace_dict))
 Out: 'tested 1: test friendly, test 2: very friendly, test 3: test friendly, test 4: very friendly, test 5: very friendly'
```